# shifting value in a matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

I have a 4x8 matrix.

```
{
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
}
```

if i input "10111101", then the process should be like:

```
{
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
}

then

{
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
}

then

{
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0

0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
}

then

{
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0

0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
}

{

0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0


0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0

0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
}
```

and this will go to the last. after finishing all column it will start again.

I actually have a matrix(4x8) of ovalshape. I used List<> and all controls are in shapecontainer. I want to change the color when I find 1. This part I can do, but I cannot think how can I shift 1,0 in the matrix.

How could I do this?

Here is my code:

int k = 0;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {                
        if(toto[i].ToString()=="1")
        {
            ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.Red;
            k = k + 1;
        }
        else if (toto[i].ToString() == "0")
        {
            ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.LawnGreen;
            k = k + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            k = k+1-1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Shift 1, 0 in the matrix"? I don't quite get it. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: It's a 4x8 matrix (rows go first).

Comment: Also, what have you tried? You should post some code as well.

Comment: int k = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
            {                
                if(toto[i].ToString()=="1")
                {
                    ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.Red;
                    k = k + 1;
                }
                else if (toto[i].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                    k = k + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = k;
                }
            }

Comment: what is the question; what is the problem description? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to make a virtual Moving LED display. the input will indicate which LED's will ON/OFF(1/0). my code yet i did is:

Comment: int k = 0; for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) { if(toto[i].ToString()=="1") { ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.Red; k = k + 1; } else if (toto[i].ToString() == "0") { ovalShape[k].FillColor = Color.LawnGreen; k = k + 1; } else { k = k; } } –

Comment: Please edit your question to put the formatted code at the end, it will be much clearer to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a variable to determine which column to display first? (I'm using firstColumn here)
(Untested)

```
void ChangeArrayDisplay(int firstColumn) //Any column can be first, from 0 to 7
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = firstColumn * 4; i < stringLength; i++) 
    {
        changeOvalColor(k, toto[i]);
        k++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstColumn * 4; i++) 
    {
        changeOvalColor(k, toto[i]);
        k++;
    }
}

void ChangeOvalColor(int index, int colorValue)
{
     if(colorValue == 0)
         ovalShape[index].FillColor = Color.Red;
     else
         ovalShape[index].FillColor = Color.LawnGreen;
}
```

I also made some changes to your code.
You should know that `k = k + 1;` is equivalent to `k++;`

**Edit**
The question has changed, but I'm still using your 8x4 format in here. You can change the code to adapt to your new situation.

Comment: I have also deleted `k = k+1-1;`, because it doesn't do anything. Plus, you should never have values different than 0 and 1, right? In my code, any non-zero value is considered to be green.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i made the colorchange done.

but the other part to shift this data from left to right is yet undone. 

Say my input is"11011011". this will change color of first two column. but my matrix has more 6 column's. i want to move this data to the next column's. like a moving LED display.

am i clear to you Msonic? And apology for poor communication skill.

Comment: You can do that with the code above. You only have to load the full matrix. Each time you call ChangeArrayDisplay(), but with a different firstColumn, the display will change, but you won't have to change the matrix.

Comment: To make a LED display, you can have a timer (I'm guessing you're using windows forms?) that calls `ChangeArrayDisplay()` with an increasing (or decreasing) `firstColumn` index every X seconds.

Comment: for (FirstColumn = 1; FirstColumn < 8; FirstColumn++)
            {
                ChangeArrayDisplay(FirstColumn, stringLength);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: That *would* work, but the program would freeze during your `thread.sleep()`.